# Disable default action on keyUp

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events, keyup

In my form, I want to use keyboard arrow keys to move between the input fields.

[Here is the Codesandbox example.](https://codesandbox.io/s/inputkeyboardnavigation-typxg?file=/src/App.js)
(Click inside the last input field and use the UP arrow key to move up to the previous sibling input field.

Code:

```
  const arrowDownPosition = React.useRef();

  const getCurElePosition = (eTarget) => {
    const mum = eTarget.parentElement.parentElement;
    const parent = mum.parentElement;
    const children = Array.from(parent.children);
    let taskNum;
    children.forEach((el, i) => {
      const elChild = el.children[0].children[0];
      if (elChild === eTarget) {
        taskNum = i;
      }
    });
    return [taskNum, parent, children, mum];
  };

  const keyUpHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.key === "ArrowUp") {
      e.target.setSelectionRange(
        arrowDownPosition.current[0],
        arrowDownPosition.current[1]
      );
    }
  };

  const keyHandler = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    const eTarget = e.target;
    const [elePosition, parent, children, mum] = getCurElePosition(eTarget);
    if (e.key === "ArrowUp") {
      let previousSiblingRef;
      children.forEach((ele, i) => {
        if (ele == mum && i - 1 >= 0) {
          previousSiblingRef = i - 1;
        }
      });
      if (previousSiblingRef) {
        const { selectionStart, selectionEnd } = eTarget;
        arrowDownPosition.current = [selectionStart, selectionEnd];
        const previousSibling =
          children[previousSiblingRef].children[0].children[0];
        previousSibling.focus();
        previousSibling.setSelectionRange(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
      }
    }
  };
```

The above solution is a hacky way of solving the problem. You can see the caret move to the start of the previous input field before its moved to my intended position. I am using `useRef` to store the value.

This is because I am unable to stop the `keyUp` default handler before my code is run?

Thank you

Comment: FWIW, and this is just my opinion, this doesn't seem like a good UX decision. Browsers already have `tab` and `shift tab` built in. If I was in an input field and it behaved unexpectedly I wouldn't bother filling out the rest of the form.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I wanted to replicate the `contenteditable` feature. My previous version had `contenteditable`, however, after resting with bugs after bugs and it started working great on Firefox, I discovered it did not work on Vivaldi, thats when I gave up and decided to rewrite using input fields. Goal is to give a rich editor like experience. Incase anyone wants to know, I have a custom requirements so contenteditable packages wont work by default.